# Characterization of $(0 ,1)$-matrices under swap of columns or rows

Tags: matrices

I have a squared $(0,1)$ matrix. How I can know if two $(0, 1)$ matrices are the same under column and rows swapping?

Moreover, how I can characterize the equivalence classes of $(0,1)$ matrices under column and row swapping?

Maybe the question is too easy or too broad, I dont know. Anyway I would appreciate A LOT any help or bibliography for this specific question. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think if you had a nice way to answer your question, you'd also have a nice way to solve the Graph Isomorphism problem.

Comment: @GerryMyerson, so this is a open problem?

Comment: Is a $(0,1)$ matrix one whose entries are either $0$ or $1$? And what exactly do you mean by column and row swapping? Do you mean transposition?

Comment: @robjohn, about 0,1: yes. About transposition... depends what you call "transposition" xD, just exchanging any column by any other column, or exchanging any row by any other row.

Comment: Graph Isomorphism is, for any particular pair of graphs, a finite problem, so not an open problem. What's open is whether there is any way to solve it significantly more efficiently than by a brute force search (and I think the betting among the experts is that there is no such way). More information at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_isomorphism_problem